# using printf for mixed multiple formats

Tags: java, format, printf, whitespace, decimal-point

I have a question on how I am supposed to use printf for a mix of multiple formats. In my case, I am trying to give a number a certain amount of spaces so that it fits perfectly In a table and I am trying to limit how many decimal places it is allowed. Below is what I have tried with printf:

```
System.out.printf("%1s%10s%27s%26s%28s%28s1.5d", typeOCar, startingMiles, endingMiles, Distance, gallons, MPG);
```

when I execute my program, it displays this:

```
run:
                                                 Gas & Mileage Calculations

Car Type           Starting Miles             Ending Miles                 Distance                  Gallons             Miles/Gallon
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Toyota Sequoia     15543                      15565                        22                        16.5          1.33333333333333331.5dBUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why 1.5d? Where is your use of %x.yf? where x and y are numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your last format specifier should be an `f` for *floating point number* using width and precision numbers: e.g., `%20.5f`
2. Many of your String specifiers, `%xs`, should likely be decimal specifiers, `%xd` where `x` is the format width.
3. If you make this change, then the corresponding argument should be a decimal number, not a String.
4. You have too many format specifiers for the number of arguments you pass in. This is nothing but basic math. Count your specifiers and your parameters.
5. Read the [Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for all the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

then use this in your code:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("00.##"); //0 = numbers before . and # numbers after .
```

and to convert any value (example here being printed out directly):

```
System.out.println(fmt.format(varName));
```